# VIM support to upload via SFTP

Tags: vim, plugins, sftp

I am used to Sublime's plugin that let's you do a mapping between your local project and a remote project.  By doing so, when you are done editing a file, you can do a right click and "Upload file" action which automatically updates the file in the remote server.

I am wondering what would be the best way to do this while programming with VIM. I am looking for an easy way to be able to map a local project to a remote one and be able to upload the file easily.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If all you want is to edit files on a remote server,
try vim's `netrw` feature:

```
vim scp://you@yourserver//path/to/directory/
```

Edit a file directly:

```
vim scp://you@yourserver//path/to/directory/somefile.txt
```

Or if you are already in `vim`, hit `ESC`, then type:

```
:e scp://you@yourserver//path/to/directory/
```

This assumes that:

1. you have `ssh` installed (usually the case for Linux or OSX; if you are on Windows then it depends).
2. you have `ssh` access to the server via some convenient method (`sshagent` and keys)

Comment: This is a good answer. However, if everytime I want to upload a file I need to do :e scp:.... is pretty tedious. I am surprised there is no plugin around to do that mapping.

Comment: You do the `:e ` thing only once. This is like directly editing the file on the remote server, as opposed to having a local copy and periodically uploading it. So when you save the file as usual (say with `:w` or `:wq`) the file on the remote server will be saved as well. What flavor of vim are you using? (Windows? Linux? Gui? Console?)

Comment: @HommerSmith, I'm surprised you didn't find [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1192).

Answer (score 1):

Most serious FTP clients let you edit remote files locally. Filezilla, gFTP, Transmit, Cyberduck, YummyFTP… they all have their own "Edit in…" button. GUI FTP clients may not be sexy hacker tools but they work *very* well.

Some of those serious FTP clients have synchronisation features or folder watchers. It might be worth your time to look around for such a feature.

Of course, you can also use Vim itself to edit a remote file via FTP or SFTP:

```
$ vim sftp://user@machine/filename
$ vim ftp://user@machne/filename
```

and list remote files:

```
$ vim sftp://user@machine/directory/
```

See `:help netrw` for more info.

Did you consider using a VCS like Subversion, Git or Mercurial?

Comment: I actually have a local project and the project in the remote server. Despite of the fact that I use GIT, I want to be able to do changes in my local and upload them via SFTP. I don't want to edit the ones in the remote server, but edit locally and upload.